# Create trigger to know who made changes in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have one table `Products` and a second `Products_audit` with two columns `User` and `Date`.

Could you please assist me in writing a trigger for table `Products` to handle this requirement:

when anybody will modify data in `Products`, I need the trigger to insert the `User` and `Date` into the `Products_audit`, fetching the current user's name who modified data and the current date when this operation took place.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried... Google for "TRIGGER after insert" and you'll find plenty of information.

Comment: In current moment nothing, I'd like to know approximately structure of that trigger

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger_name] ON  [DBO].[Products] 
   AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO ProductsAudit
    SELECT suser_sname(),getdate() FROM inserted
END
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for assistance. I've tried following: `CREATE TRIGGER Super1 ON  Products
   AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Products_audit (Date, [User])
    SELECT suser_sname(),getdate() FROM Products

END` Could you please take a look and correct me where I was wrong cause I receive error when try insert data in table Products: Syntax error converting datetime from character string.

Comment: It looks like you have the date and user fields swapped.